# CAN library error in Python: [WinError 2] system cannot find the file

Tags: python, dll, can-bus

I would like to use  CANlib in my PyCharm virtual environment. But since I installed it, when I run my code it constantly gives this error: [image: Python Error]

The code I am trying to use:

```
from canlib import canlib

num_channels = canlib.getNumberOfChannels()
print(f"Found {num_channels} channels")
for ch in range(num_channels):
    chd = canlib.ChannelData(ch)
    print(f"{ch}. {chd.channel_name} ({chd.card_upc_no} / {chd.card_serial_no})")
```

The code is from original website: https://pypi.org/project/canlib/

I searched this error and found some causes which I think could be the reason but I don't know the solutions:

1. It can be 32-bit 64-bit dll problem, but the source code has both situations in its library dllLoader.py:

   ```
    dir = os.getcwd()
    installDir = os.environ.get("KVDLLPATH", "")
    if not installDir:
        if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
            if platform.architecture()[0] == "32bit":
            aKeyName = r"SOFTWARE\KVASER AB\CanlibSDK"
        else:
            aKeyName = r"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\KVASER AB\CanlibSDK"
        aReg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
        aKey = winreg.OpenKey(aReg, aKeyName)
        aValue = winreg.QueryValueEx(aKey, "")
        baseDir = str(aValue[0])

        if 8 * struct.calcsize("P") == 32:
            installDir = os.path.join(baseDir, "Bin")
        else:
            installDir = os.path.join(baseDir, "bin_x64")
        installDir = os.path.realpath(installDir)
   ```
2. Also I checked out if my interpreter path involves required dll files. (canlib32.dll etc.)
3. I uninstalled the library and installed it all over again.

These all didn't work.
Is there anyone be able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and been scratching my head on it for awhile. Changing the KVDLLPATH helped me

```
import os

# Set the KVDLLPATH environment variable to the directory containing canlib32.dll
os.environ['KVDLLPATH'] = r'C:\Program Files\Kvaser\Drivers'

# Now import canlib
from canlib import canlib
```